# WSO2 ESB: Simple XSLT Message Transformation Issue

Tags: xslt, wso2-esb

As will be clear below, my XSLT does not wrap the for-each expression in a parent element as I need it to. I need all the **message** elements to be wrapped in a **messages** parent element.

I have a local entry storing the following XSLT Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" version="1.0">
<xsl:param name="page_id"/>
<xsl:param name="thread_id"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <messages xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </messages>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="//soapenv:Body/jsonObject">
    <xsl:for-each select="/data">
    <message xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <Page_ID><xsl:value-of select="$page_id"/></Page_ID>
      <Thread_ID><xsl:value-of select="$thread_id"/></Thread_ID>
      <Message_ID><xsl:value-of select="id"/></Message_ID>
      <From_Name><xsl:value-of select="from/name"/></From_Name>
      <From_ID><xsl:value-of select="from/id"/></From_ID>
      <To_Name><xsl:value-of select="to/data/name"/></To_Name>
      <To_ID><xsl:value-of select="to/data/id"/></To_ID>
      <Message><xsl:value-of select="message"/></Message>
      <Attachment_URL><xsl:value-of select="attachments/data/image_data/url"/></Attachment_URL>
      <Created_Date><xsl:value-of select="created_time"/></Created_Date>
    </message>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm calling the XSLT mediator via a proxy service like so:

```
<xslt key="Facebook_Transform_Messages" source="$body">
  <property name="page_id" expression="$ctx:page_id"/>
  <property name="thread_id" expression="$ctx:thread_id"/>
</xslt>
```

The data being passed into the service looks like this:

```
<jsonObject>
  <data>
    <from>
      <name>James Strain</name>
      <email>10153389835751312@facebook.com</email>
      <id>10153389835751312</id>
    </from>
    <to>
      <data>
        <name>Symphony Council</name>
        <email>409521282507981@facebook.com</email>
        <id>409521282507981</id>
      </data>
    </to>
    <created_time>2016-02-03T13:09:08+0000</created_time>
    <message>test55</message>
    <id>m_mid.1454504948354:03a56a0154cef57406</id>
  </data>
</jsonObject>
```

After the transformation:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <message xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <Page_ID>409521282507981</Page_ID>
  <Thread_ID>t_mid.1450744554432:5789f650412eb3fd70</Thread_ID>
  <Message_ID>m_mid.1454553062384:420772e48d9196bd75</Message_ID>
  <From_Name>James Strain</From_Name>
  <From_ID>10153389835751312</From_ID>
  <To_Name>Symphony Council</To_Name>
  <To_ID>409521282507981</To_ID>
  <Message>test70</Message>
  <Attachment_URL/>
  <Created_Date>2016-02-04T02:31:02+0000</Created_Date>
  </message>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope
```

### Update 1

I've updated my stylesheet according to the answer provided by Cis below. However it has not solved my issue. Still, WSO2 will not follow the XSLT exactly and actually wrap my for-each operation in an element! I've tested this with a copy of the payload data (the whole SOAP envelope) [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) and it works fine! What's going on?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:param name="page_id"/>
<xsl:param name="thread_id"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="jsonObject">
    <xsl:element name="messages">
         <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <xsl:element name="message">
               <xsl:element name="Page_ID"><xsl:value-of select="$page_id"/></xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="Thread_ID"><xsl:value-of select="$thread_id"/></xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="Message_ID"><xsl:value-of select="id"/></xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="From_Name"><xsl:value-of select="from/name"/></xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="From_ID"><xsl:value-of select="from/id"/></xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="To_Name"><xsl:value-of select="to/data/name"/></xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="To_ID"><xsl:value-of select="to/data/id"/></xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="Message"><xsl:value-of select="message"/></xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="Attachment_URL"><xsl:value-of select="attachments/data/image_data/url"/></xsl:element>
               <xsl:element name="Created_Date"><xsl:value-of select="created_time"/></xsl:element>
               </xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in XPath expressions in your XSLT code:

1. `//soapenv:Body/jsonObject`: the trailing `//` do not make sense in a `match` attribute, as the XSLT processor will go through every element, regardsless at which level they are, checking if it fits the `match`. More severe may be that in your sample input code, there is no `soapenv:Body` element, which means, the template `match` attribute can never evaluate to true, thus, the template will never be executed. If, like in your sample code, `jsonObject` is used only at this particular position (as opposed to: it is **not** used in places in your input XML where you do not want it to be processed by this template) you can simple put it like `<xsl:template match="jsonObject">`
2. In `<xsl:for-each select="/data">`, the `/` is wrong. You are trying to select the root element (which is not `data`), to select child elements, simply do `select="data"`

Comment: I guess, it's a namespace problem. Does your data input look excatley the way you provided as example - being in no namespace at all? What is the output you get right now?

Comment: Hi Cis, everything is exactly the same. No namespaces besides the usual soapenv namespace. Output is the same again, the wrapping "messages" element it simply skipped :/

Comment: Just to make sure your template is actually processed: Write "foo" between `<xsl:element name="messages">` and `<xsl:for-each select="data">` and see whether you see "foo" in the output. If it's there, then I guess, the problem lies somewhere at a later point in your toolchain/output receiver or whatever. At some point, the wrapping `messages` element is probably removed/just the content passed. If it's not there: Maybe an old version of your XSLT file is stored in a cache somewhere and still used, so that your changes don't apply.  (I had that problem within exist-db.)